# Change the color of CursorLine underline

Tags: cursorline

```
set cursorline
highlight CursorLine cterm=underdotted ctermbg=NONE
```

This creates a nice dotted line under the row that my cursor is on.

- `ctermbg` causes the whole row to be highlighted (which I do not want)
- `ctermfg` changes the color of the underline, but also highlights the text in that color (which I do not want)

I'd like to change *only* the underline color (which is, when everything is unaltered, white). Is that possible?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends whether you use the graphical user interface or the terminal user interface.

For either UI, the *underdotted* attributes may not be available as descibed in `:help attr-list` or `:help underdotted` (they link to the same `:help` item). If a certain setting does not work, it's best to change to a configuration that's known to be working and modify step by step.

#### Terminal user interface

The exact outcome depends on the capabilities of your terminal emulator.

```
:highlight CursorLine cterm=underdotted ctermul=white
```

See `:help highlight-ctermul` for the documentation on the color terminal underline highlight argument.

Depending on what's already set, you may have to unset additional arguments like this:

```
:highlight CursorLine cterm=underdotted ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermul=white
```

#### Graphical user interface

For the GUI, the `gui*` attributes are used instead of the `cterm*` ones. Namely, the `guisp` controls the color of strikethrough and underline (apparently also underdotted but that's undocumented). See `:help highlight-guisp`.
The command would look like this:

```
:highlight CursorLine gui=underdotted guifg=NONE guibg=NONE guisp=white
```

#### Putting it all together

To get a consistent look across TUI and GUI versions, both commands can be combined into:

```
:highlight CursorLine cterm=underdotted ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermul=white gui=underdotted guifg=NONE guibg=NONE guisp=white
```

*Note: in my local setup, underdotted lines are not supported, neither in TUI or GUI versions. At the same time, underlines in GUI were always in `guifg` color. Parts of this answer are based on OP's observations.*

Comment: ah! thank you. i didn't see reference to `ctermul` in any of my searches; it didn't work for me, but it _did_ lead me to [this](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/6011) (which points out the `guisp` option)

would you mind editing your post to include that?

Comment: @AmagicalFishy based on your question, I was assuming you were using the terminal user interface. *You* can edit it my answer yourself. Even better - post an answer of your own! This is encouraged by this site and will help others to find your solution quickly.

Comment: I couldn't wait and edited my answer. Feel free to post an answer of your own anyway.

Comment: I am actually! I'm not sure why `guisp` is the one I need to use to tell you the truth

Comment: You are using the TUI version but you need to set `guisp`? This doesn't sound right. You might ask a new question and include the terminal emulator you use, the output of `:version`, a minimal `vimrc` to reproduce the behavior and a screenshot. However,  I'm almost certain there's something in your setup we missed.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy it just occurred to me that using `:set termguicolors` would use `guifg` and `guibg` in the terminal. Might be that also applies to `guisp` (without being documented). You don't have this option set by any chance?